# Detailed sql Selection with order By

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I wonder if I could do a specific selection of datas from mysql database:

Basic set is:
**`SELECT Lastname, Firstname, Partner FROM xy-table ORDER BY Lastname Asc`**

OK, works well..
In the selection of the Lastnames (A-Z) i would like to have the names of the Partners first (A-Z) and THEN the rest of the names ...

---

### table is:

Lastname-------Firstname-------Partner----

1. Ashok    -------      Anton ----------        0
2. Bshok    -------      Berni ------------        1
3. Dshok    -------      Thomas  --------       0
4. Rods     ---------      Dean    -----------       1

---

the result should be in this order
(Ordered by Lastname (A-Z) and within that column by Partner (A-Z)

1. **Bshok     -      Berni**    (1 =Partner)
2. **Rods      -      Dean**     (1 =Partner)
3. **Ashok - Anton**  ---  (0 = Not a Partner)
4. **Dshok - Thomas**  --- (0 = Not a Partner)

Is that possible????

Comment: You can use two fields order by clause...`ORDER BY Lastname Asc, Partners ASC`

Comment: Your description of what you want seems to be the opposite of the example output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Partner` as the first criteria with Descending option and then `Lastname` as the second criteria with ascending option

```
SELECT Lastname, Firstname, Partner 
FROM xy-table 
ORDER BY Partner DESC, Lastname ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Lastname, Firstname, Partner FROM xy-table ORDER BY Partner Asc, Lastname
```